# How to get all {% include ... %} and {% extend ... %} tags before/after render Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Using Django, I have html template "name.html" with content like:

```
{% extends "some.html" %}
{% for page in pages %}
  {% include page.html_template_path %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will include template which path is stored in **page.html_template_path**.
Important part is: every html template may extend/include another html templates inside itself.

**How to recursively get all templates (path to every template) loaded via {% extend ... %} and {% include %} tags ?**

- RegEx is not solution (path to template may be inside variable/context/{% for %} tag etc.
- replacing built-in {% extend %} and {% include %} tags with custom tags is solution, but not good in my project

I found https://github.com/edoburu/django-template-analyzer/blob/master/template_analyzer/djangoanalyzer.py
but it cant properly treat nested {% for %} tags etc.